# Add htbp to all float environments

Tags: macros, floats, optional-arguments

In short: *How can I add the optional parameters `[htbp]` to all float environments?*

Ideally, I don't want to define a custom new environment, but add these options "with a hack" like `\g@addto@macro\@floatboxreset{...}`, maybe in the preamble or in a custom package (with `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`).

##### MWE:

```latex
% Instead of this
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{A dummy image.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

```latex
% Have this
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}

\makeatletter
% !!Some command that adds `[htbp]`
% to all float environments
\makeatother

\begin{document}

% Note that `[htbp]` is missing, since it is
% automatically implied.
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{A dummy image.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The document class should define (maybe inheriting it from another loaded class)

```
\fps@figure
\fps@table
```

to contain the default position specifiers.

You can add, before `\begin{document}`,

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\fps@figure}{htbp}
\renewcommand{\fps@table}{htbp}
\makeatother
```

and after this typing

```
\begin{figure}
```

would be the same as typing

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
```

(the same for `table`). You can still override the default by saying, for instance

```
\begin{figure}[!hp]
```

or whatever particular choice you need.